No more GNOME gui after installing wine via aptitude
I followed the chosen answer here to install Wine on Ubuntu 22.04 as the instructions of WINEHQ gave an error that not all dependencies were met.enter image description here
So after that some icons and the Gnome gui looked strange, so I thought a reboot would help.
Now I have only the command line. How can I fix this?
Thanks a lot and meanwhile I'll keep searching for an answer.

@user:1134215 Originally I wrote: a reboot does good (as my German colleague often says: Ein Reboot tut gut, because it rhymes. It has nothing to do with correct grammar.

ok found
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

For the people who can not interpret the second line themselves: if you only have the Command Line, then these commends will reinstall the Ubuntu Desktop.
It reboots itself when ready.

What does this mean? If it is an answer it needs more details.

I think the second line is self explanatory
